# What is the difference between a work of fiction and a never-before-instantiated property?

Tags: metaphysics

Say we wanted to make a design a new kind of table, philosophically would that design represent a never-before-instantiated property of being 'the new kind of table', or a fictional object 'the new kind of table'?

When we discuss 'the new table' before it's made then would that make it part of fiction? Or are we actually discussing a platonic entity that is the property of being 'the new table' before it is instantiated?

Comment: It happens usually when someone design a new object: we do not call it "a work of fiction" but a new design or project.

Comment: Our three conditions on building new tables would be (A) the shape, (B) the coloration, and (C) the material. "A table with a shape no table has had before, colored over in a novel way, made out of a previously never-used material," is a somewhat dubious description if we don't know all the tables there have ever been. Anyway, "Build a table in shape X, with coloration Y, out of material Z," doesn't clearly seem to require a fictional table object *or* a haecceitic table property?

Comment: However, "What is the difference between a description of a fictional object and the description of a never-before-instantiated property?" is a good enough question, so maybe reworking the example and reframing the OP as such would help smooth the OP out.

Comment: @KristianBerry this is exactly the question I was trying to ask. What is the difference between a description of a physical object and the description of a never-befire-instantiated property

Comment: You seem to be missing a third possibility: that what is described is an abstract table, which is not the same as a fictional table, and which is not any sort of essentialist property.

Comment: Your "new kind of table" differs from an "existing kind of table" in kind or in degree? Is "new style/genre of table" more appropriate here? The Platonic *idea* of table is nothing new...

Comment: These are officially called *intentional objects*,  objects of thought, and there are two approaches to dealing with them. The more straightforward one goes back to scholastics and was developed in modern times by Brentano, where they are "non-existent" abstract objects (not really platonic, as they lack causal powers). The other goes back to Russell, and on it "fictional" objects or properties are never discussed at all, it is only a manner of speaking using definite descriptions, see [SEP, Intentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/#TrueNegaExisBeli).

Answer (score 1):

The crucial concept here is **realizability** of a thing.

Given the current state of the world, a certain thing might be realizable or not.

Once a thing is realizable, given the current state of the world, it is a potential thing, untill it is realized, when it is an actual thing.

What is the existential status of a potential thing is a matter of discussion. Certainly if we assume that the future state of the world can be described by a set of possibilities, then that thing is part of that set. Or, even better, this thing is not excluded from a future state of the world. This is one way that a thing can exist as a potentiality (ie **it is not impossible to be realized at some future instant given the current state of the world, although it is not necessary to be realized either**).

Certainly as far as a description of the thing is there (either written or in thought), it exists as a description of something (regardless of the realizability of that something).

Even an existing thing (that has been realized) can become an impossibility at some future instant in this world. So the existential status of actual and potential things need not be static. In this sense, there is a huge difference to Platonic Ideas, which are eternally static.

So the design of a new table, not yet existing, can be either a potential thing, or not even realizable in this world, given its current state.

Usually works of fiction are concerned with things not realizable, or don't even care about realizability per se, whereas for engineering designs realizability is a prerequisite. Although this is not absolute.

> Quiz Question: Where do lies live?

References:

1. [Potentiality and Actuality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiality_and_actuality)

Comment: Thank you Nikos, brilliantly put

Comment: I'd say works of fiction don't care about realizability, in some sense. There is no requirement for fiction to only talk about unrealizable things.

Comment: @kutschkem yes this is better formulation: works of fiction don't care about realizability or not, whereas for engineering designs it is a prerequisite